# My terminal crashes upon opening

Tags: command-line

Right when I open terminal, it closes without me seeing anything. I have searched endlessly and still haven't found a solution. I am using Ubuntu 13.04. When I open xterm, login as root, and type "gnome-terminal" a terminal pops up, but it won't open with the dash.

Comment: Probably some permissions error. Try running the following command: `sudo chown -R USER:USER "$HOME"`. Replace 'USER' with your username.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried synaptic package manager ?

remove konsole ( resp. terminal ) completely - then re-install it again.

Comment: I tried to re install gnome-terminal, but it still didn't work.

Comment: It's almost like there's a script to close my terminal right when it opens.